# Unable to display same line chart twice using chart.js and jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

In the below code i am trying to generate a line chart based on random variables using chart.js.

I am trying to print the same chart on two different tabs. However, it would only display on the first tab and not the second one.

I have no problems in displaying the chart. It is just that it would not work on tab2 ? can someone point me my error ? I tried to check in the console but it does not display any error.

head

```
<head> 
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
  <script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>

  <script src="js/Chart.js"></script>

   <script>
  $(function() {
    $( "#tabs" ).tabs();
  });
  </script>


</head>
```

.
body

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li><a href="#tabs-1">Capacity - Hourly</a></li>
    <li><a href="#tabs-2">Capacity - Daily</a></li>
  </ul>

  <div id="tabs-1">
        <div style="width:30%">
            <div>
                <canvas id="canvas" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>

  <!-- End of Tab 1 -->

  <div id="tabs-2">

        <div style="width:30%">
            <div>
                <canvas id="canvas2" height="300" width="300"></canvas>
            </div>
        </div>

  </div>
  <!-- End of Tab 2 -->

</div>


<script>
        var randomScalingFactor = function(){ return Math.round(Math.random()*100)};
        var lineChartData = {
            labels : ["01:00","02:00","03:00","04:00","05:00","06:00","07:00", "08:00","09:00","10:00","11:00","12:00","13:00","14:00","15:00","16:00","17:00","18:00","19:00","20:00","21:00", "22:00","23:00","24:00"],
            datasets : [
                {
                    label: "My First dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(54,61,251,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(54,61,251,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor() ]
                },
                {
                    label: "My Second dataset",
                    fillColor : "rgba(251,54,54,0.2)",
                    strokeColor : "rgba(251,54,54,1)",
                    pointColor : "rgba(251,54,54,1)",
                    pointStrokeColor : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightFill : "#fff",
                    pointHighlightStroke : "rgba(251,54,54,1)",
                    data : [randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(), randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor(),randomScalingFactor() ]
                }
            ]

        }

    window.onload = function(){
        var ctx = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });

        var ctx2 = document.getElementById("canvas2").getContext("2d");
        window.myLine = new Chart(ctx2).Line(lineChartData, {
            responsive: true
        });

    }
    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: you assigned both charts to window.myLine, so maybe that's why it only show up once? What is window.myLine anyway? Maybe assign the charts to different variables.